# Highlight a particular road/railway line on Google Maps without specifying source and destinations

Tags: driving, maps, scenic-routes, google-maps

On Google Maps we usually look for a route between two places by specifying them by names. But how to highlight a route without specifying any place names? For example, if I enter Tokyo and Osaka in source and destination boxes on Maps it can show the main route and any alternate routes between the two cities. But what if I want to highlight only a road lets say if I want to look for Pacific Highway in Australia, the suggestions shown to me are of cities and if I click on one of them the Maps takes me to that spot on the map. But I want to highlight the whole of Pacific Highway and not any specific spot on the highway. Is there a way to do that in Google Maps?

Comment: You might also try Google Earth desktop app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not Google maps - this can be achieved on Open Street Maps - eg. https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3574625#map=7/34.153/134.934 (It's a long road so this may take some time to load)

You can either do this by directly searching for the name of the road in the search bar, but you'll probably find it easier to right click on a section of the road. Clicking "Query features" and then the name of the road you have just clicked on. And then scroll down to the "Part of" section - clicking any of these options will highlight the whole route.

This does depend on someone having created the relation in Open Street Map, so the more major a road you're looking for, the more likley it is to be present.